# Jsoup Html parser to get content

Tags: jsoup

I need to extract $349,900 from below html.
How do I do that?

```
<p class="price asking help ">
                <span class="title">Asking Price:</span><b>$349,900<span class="help" title="The total asking price of the business for sale."><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></span></b>
            </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract this price using [`Element.select(String cssQuery)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select-java.lang.String-) method with `p.price b` CSS selector, e.g.

```
String html = "<p class=\"price asking help \">\n" +
            "                <span class=\"title\">Asking Price:</span><b>$349,900<span class=\"help\" title=\"The total asking price of the business for sale.\"><i class=\"fa fa-question-circle\"></i></span></b>\n" +
            "            </p>";

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

String price = doc.select("p.price b").first().text();

System.out.println(price);
```

#### Output

```
$349,900
```

You can see how it works here: <kbd>[Demo](https://jdoodle.com/a/5B2)</kbd>